# EMGU 3.2 VideoCapture constructor hangs application

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. After spending many hours fighting this I am at my wits end. At this point I am just trying to get the EMGU example applications to run.

Just the facts ...

- Applications hang at the line "_capture = new VideoCapture();"
- All other versions of EMU were uninstalled
- I am using the latest version of EMGU (3.2.0.2682)
- No error message or exceptions are displayed
- I am using a webcam, logitech C615
- Camera works with logitech software
- Using a coworker's computer the camera worked after a fresh install of EMGU
- Any example program that uses VideoCapture also just hangs the app
- The app I am focusing on is C:\Emgu\emgucv-windesktop 3.2.0.2682\bin\Example.CameraCapture.exe
- Attaching a debugger provided no useful information
- Once the applications are started the only way to kill them is to restart the pc
- Other EMGU applications like faceDetection work just fine

[List of running processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJAQj.jpg)

I have a feeling it has something to do with a driver conflict, a library issue, or camera format issue. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

NickJ, if there is a driver conflict it is not in EmguCV. Emgu CV includes no driver or drivers that might cause conflicts with a Camera. It only use existing drivers through OpenCV, which uses platform drivers to read camera stream or video files.

I long ago quit using EmguCV/OpenCv to handle my video capture. I found that these SDKs performed wonderfully at computer vision application and less wonderfully at capture.

I know people use them for capture and some have success but judging by the number of posts on SO asking about video capture I would suggest most have issues.

As for your specific problem I would be wondering how so many copies are getting started. You could download OpenCV, build it and debug through the code to see what is going on.

Doug

Comment: I was doing some testing and ended up starting a few too many instances with no way to kill them. 

I am at that point where I really don't know of any other means to troubleshoot the problem and I was looking for suggestions.

As for alternatives what do you recommend? Microsoft Expression Encoder?

Comment: I use Medialooks MFormat SDK (https://www.medialooks.com/). However, it is not inexpensive and does a good number of things you may not need. The code seems tight and the support is excellent.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a conflict with a black magic video recorder device. I removed the card from the PC and everything started working. What a headache ...

Comment: Yes. Rarely are the problems with conflicting drivers the fault of EmguCV/OpenCV. 

Glad you found the problem!

Comment: Can you give me more details? I think I'm having the same problem with version 3.2, they are throwing null exception, so I don't really what really happens inside